# Why should an outer measure give 0 on an empty set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

A standard definition of **outer measure** on a set $X$ is a function
$$\rho:2^X\to[0,\infty]$$
satisfying the following properties:

1. $\rho(\varnothing)=0$
2. $A\subseteq B\implies\rho(A)\leq\rho(B)$
3. $\rho(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\rho(A_n)$

A subset $E\subseteq X$ is then said to be **$\rho$-measurable** if
$$\rho(A)=\rho(A\cap E)+\rho(A\cap E^c)$$
for all $A\subseteq X$.
My question is: Why is the first condition necessary? As far as I can see, none of  the important properties of outer measure and measurable set seems to require this condition.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but unless I am mistaken, $\rho(\emptyset)>0$ would imply that there are no measurable sets at all (choose $A=E$ in the definition).

Comment: If $\rho(\emptyset) > 0$, then there will be no measurable set, **unless** $\rho$ is identically $+\infty$ (in this case, all sets will be measurable).

Comment: If $\rho(\emptyset) >0$ then, for any measurable set, we would have $$\rho(\emptyset)=\rho(A\cap \emptyset)+\rho(A\cap \emptyset^c)= \rho(\emptyset) +  \rho(A) \tag{1}$$ Since , $\emptyset \subseteq A$, we have $0 < \rho(\emptyset) \leq \rho(A)$. So, the only way to satisfy $(1)$ is having $$\rho(\emptyset)= \infty$$ and so, for all $A\subseteq X$, $$\rho(A) = \infty$$ In this case, all sets will be measurable. Such $\rho$ is OK, but not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, for any measurable non empty set we would have
$\rho(A) = \rho(A \bigcap \emptyset) + \rho(A \bigcap X) = \rho(\emptyset) + \rho(A)$, so $\rho(\emptyset)$ must be $0$ if a measurable set $A$ exists

Comment: If $\rho(\emptyset) > 0$, then there will be no measurable set, **unless** $\rho$ is identically $+\infty$ (in this case, all sets will be measurable).